# how to get fields from parent in hierarchical model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have  schemas of user, and pet.
User can have a few pets.
I need the user name that the pet belongs to.

```
var petSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: false },
});
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name     : { type: String, default: 'New User', required: true },
 });
```

I try:

```
Pet.find({name:'koko'},"user user.name ", function(err,user){
    res.send(user);
});
```

But I don't get the user name.

Comment: You are attempting a join? Well, there are no joins in mongodb. You either embed the user info in the pet or do the join itself on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method

i.e.

```
Pet
.findOne({ .... })
.populate('user')
.exec(function (err, pet) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  res.send(pet.user)
})
```